# Counting lack of a condition when joining tables

Tags: sql-server

I'm sure this isn't that hard but I can't figure out the words to search for the answer online.  Here is the situation:

I have two tables, Transaction and Transaction Detail.  I need to modify records on Transaction that DON'T have a particular value when joining tables.

```
Transaction           Transaction Detail

Tran ID tran_type     Tran ID   Tranhead_id
1       45              1           145
2       3               1           148
3       45              2           230
                        2           467
                        3           220
                        3           310
```

I need to join these tables by tran_id and then select the Transaction records with tran_type 45 that don't have a matching record on Transaction detail with tranhead_id = 145.  In this case tran_id 3 would be the only record selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an exists clause here:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM [Transaction] t
WHERE
    tran_type = 45 AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Transaction Detail] td
                WHERE td.[Tran ID] = t.[Tran ID] AND td.Tranhead_id = 145);
```